# Chossing between visual c++ and gcc to compile c++ programs mainly for studying purposes

Tags: gcc, visual-studio-2013

I am moving from g++ to visual studio mainly for c++ coding , i wanted to ask that whether microsoft's c++ compiler supports all the features of c++11 and c++14 as supported by g++ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)'s a compatibility table for various compilers. 
You should look under the **MSVC** column to see what support offers the Microsoft compiler.

At a quick glance it seems that they implement most of the same features (using gcc 5 and MSVC 14 as reference), although there are small differences.

Comment: whats that improving std::pair feature?

Comment: It's a proposal for a c++17 standard feature. You can find a link to a proposal's paper in the "Paper(s)" column.

Comment: here's a link to the proposal http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4387.html